# Flutter Multiple Nested List inside a page view with both having vertical scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for a way to add list views inside pageview and both of them should scroll vertically.

[I found one solution.](https://mak95.medium.com/nested-scrolling-listview-inside-pageview-in-flutter-a57b7a6241b1)

```
class NestedContainerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedContainerWidgetState createState() => _NestedContainerWidgetState();
}

class _NestedContainerWidgetState extends State<NestedContainerWidget> {
  PageController _pageController;
  ScrollController _listScrollController;
  ScrollController _activeScrollController;
  Drag _drag;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    _listScrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    _listScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    if (_listScrollController.hasClients &&
        _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext != null) {
      final RenderBox renderBox =
          _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext.findRenderObject();
      if (renderBox.paintBounds
          .shift(renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero))
          .contains(details.globalPosition)) {
        _activeScrollController = _listScrollController;
        _drag = _activeScrollController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
        return;
      }
    }
    _activeScrollController = _pageController;
    _drag = _pageController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
  }


  /*
   * If the listView is on Page 1, then change the condition as "details.primaryDelta < 0" and
   * "_activeScrollController.position.pixels ==  _activeScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent"
   */
  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (_activeScrollController == _listScrollController &&
        details.primaryDelta > 0 &&
        _activeScrollController.position.pixels ==
            _activeScrollController.position.minScrollExtent) {
      _activeScrollController = _pageController;
      _drag?.cancel();
      _drag = _pageController.position.drag(
          DragStartDetails(
              globalPosition: details.globalPosition, localPosition: details.localPosition),
          _disposeDrag);
    }
    _drag?.update(details);
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    _drag?.end(details);
  }

  void _handleDragCancel() {
    _drag?.cancel();
  }

  void _disposeDrag() {
    _drag = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        VerticalDragGestureRecognizer:
            GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(), (VerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
          instance
            ..onStart = _handleDragStart
            ..onUpdate = _handleDragUpdate
            ..onEnd = _handleDragEnd
            ..onCancel = _handleDragCancel;
        })
      },
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
          ListView(
            controller: _listScrollController,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: List.generate(
              20,
              (int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a simple solution and it only supports one list view and i need it to support multiple list views.

I need it to support multiple nested page views and it starts behaving badly when i put multiple lists in the page view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After searching further, i found someone solved it [here.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50946#issuecomment-1268148437)**

**Use [Nested Scroll View](https://pub.dev/packages/nested_scroll_views) package**.

```
flutter pub add nested_scroll_views
```

**After installing, import it.**

```
import 'package:nested_scroll_views/nested_scroll_views.dart';
```

**Here's a small example if you are interested.**

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nested_scroll_views/nested_scroll_views.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
        dragDevices: PointerDeviceKind.values.toSet(),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('nested_scroll_views')),
        body: NestedPageView(
          wantKeepAlive: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            NestedListView.builder(
              wantKeepAlive: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            ),
            const Text('Page 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> [More documentation here.](https://pub.dev/packages/nested_scroll_views)